# Pass editingDidChange Text Value From TableView Cell to Model

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView with multiple sections and would like to use editingDidChange in each cell to update the text fields.  I can pass data easily enough from the UITableView cell's class to the ViewController that will update the array model, however I can't think of a way to pass along info on which cell is being edited (and therefore which index in the array should be changed).

I've used sender.tag in similar scenarios before, however the tag's only count up from each section when headers are involved.  How can I tell the ViewController what cell is being edited?

Thanks!

```
//TableView cell class

    @IBAction func textField(_ sender: UITextField) {
      updateTextForDelegate.didUpdate(text: sender.text ?? "") //using editingDidChange
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this to get cell `indexpath.row` for finding which cell editing.

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    var v : UIView = textField
              repeat { v = v.superview! }
              while !(v is UITableViewCell)
              let cell = v as! FeedbackTableViewCell // or UITableViewCell or whatever
              let ip = self.tableview.indexPath(for: cell)
              textField.text = cell.anstxt.text
              // and now we have the index path! update the model
              let arrlist = arrfeedback[ip?.row ?? 0]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your cellForRowAt method, you can assign your textField tag as follows:

```
cell.yourTextField.tag = (indexPath.section * 100) + (indexPath.row)
```

Then in your `textFieldDidBeginEditing` you can get the indexPath as follows:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let tag = textField.tag
    let sectionBeingEdited = tag / 100
    let rowBeingEdited = tag%100
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowBeingEdited, section: sectionBeingEdited)
    let cell = self.servicesTable.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    // you have got your cell

}
```

> NOTE: This is just a hack to get the indexPath considering the max
>   number of section could be 100. You can increase the value from 100 to whatever you want.